# How can I get syntastic to install properly?

Tags: vim, python

I followed the exact steps listed on Syntastic's GitHub [page](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) to install it as a Pathogen bundle, but I'm not getting any Syntastic feedback at all in vim. Their FAQ states this is normally caused by `flake8` or `pylint` missing from the path, but I verified that `flake8` exists there.

When I open vim and run `:SyntasticInfo` with a python file open, I see:

```
Syntastic: active mode enabled
Syntastic info for filetype:
Available checker(s):
Currently enabled checker(s):
```

but I expected "Syntastic info for filetype: python" at the very least. Am I missing an installation step?

For reference, I'm running OSX Mavericks 10.9.2, and I have macports for Python 2.7, pyflakes, flake8:

```
$ which flake8
/opt/local/bin/flake8

$ echo $PATH
/Users/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/tony/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/tony/Developer/tools/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/Users/tony/Developer/tools/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools:/Users/tony/Developer/tools/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/17.0.0:/Users/tony/bin/gradle-1.9/bin:/Users/tony/bin/apache-maven-3.1.1/bin:/Users/tony/bin/wls1036_dev:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks as though the `'filetype'` option is not set.  You can check with `:verbose set ft?`.  Do you have a `:filetype plugin on` line (or similar) in your vimrc file?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what was different, but I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/nicholasserra/4999143) that installed everything for me. Now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the `'filetype'` option is not set. You can check with `:verbose set ft?`.  If you want this to be set automatically when you open a file, then add at least

```
:filetype on
```

to your vimrc file.  See `:help filetypes` and especially the section `:help :filetype-overview`.

In the comments, you mention a gist that worked.  One of the lines that it adds to your vimrc file is

```
:filetype plugin indent on
```